# How to save all values from the searching result in another list?

Tags: python-3.x, string, list, full-text-search

I have two list containing full sentences and phrases:

```
my_sentence=['This is string', 'This is string too', 'That is not string', 'That are not sentence']
my_phrase=['This is', 'That is']
```

I try to find the string in `my_sentence` that contains `my_phrase`. For the sentence that is match, I split the sentence using `my_phrase` and put the rest of sentences in another list, let say `my_result`. However, I also want to save the sentence that is not match in `my_result`.

The expected result in `my_result` is:

```
my_result=['string','string too', 'not string', 'That are not sentence']
```

I have tried this code:

```
result=[]
for sentence in my_sentence:
  for phrase in my_phrase:
    if phrase in sentence:
            res=sentence.split(phrase)
            result.append(res)
    else:
      res=sentence
      result.append(res)

print(result)
```

However, I got this result:

```
[['', ' string'], 'This is string', ['', ' string too'], 'This is string too', 'That is not string', ['', ' not string'], 'That are not sentence', 'That are not sentence']
```

Can somebody help me to fix my code?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What if more than one phrase is in a sentence?

Comment: You can't add the full sentence (when none of the phrases appear) until you have checked all of the phrases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use `re` module:

```py
import re

my_sentence = [
    "This is string",
    "This is string too",
    "That is not string",
    "That are not sentence",
]

my_phrase = ["This is", "That is"]

pat = re.compile("|".join(map(re.escape, my_phrase)))

out = [pat.sub("", s).strip() for s in my_sentence]
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
['string', 'string too', 'not string', 'That are not sentence']
```